# Installing pylab on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, installation

I've looked at many questions on this issue, but none seem to help. I am new to Python and programming. I am not sure if installing matplotlib is what I need to do, but it was the link given in my textbook (I am self studying, so there's no one I can ask).

I downloaded the newest version of Python, 2.7.10, and then went to [here](http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html#install-osx-binaries) and followed the instructions.

In Terminal.app,

```
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
  Found existing installation: pip 6.1.1
     Uninstalling pip-6.1.1:
       Successfully uninstalled pip-6.1.1
Successfully installed pip-7.0.1 wheel-0.24.0
```

Yet when I run my code, which begins with:

```
import pylab
from rcParamsSettings import *
import random
```

I end up getting

```
ImportError: No module named pylab
```

Can someone please help me figure this out? I have no idea what to do now.

Comment: which instructions were you following? There are plenty of different ways to install matplotlib on the linked website

Comment: @cel The section titled "Installing OSX binary wheels"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you ran the instructions to (re)install `pip`, but you did not yet run the instruction that uses `pip` to install `matplotlib`, i.e.:

```
pip install matplotlib
```